# Can not display list with ListView in another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, manifest

I am trying to display some data from DB in Activity 2 after starting intent from Activity 1, like:

```
{       case R.id.buttonRead:

            intent = new Intent(this, ListDataActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

            break;
}
```

ListDataActivity has the following coding:

```
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_data);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view_all_data);

        String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView_name_reflect,
                R.id.textView_last_name_reflect };

        // create Adapter

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item, datasource.getAllEmployees(), from, to,
                FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        // make adapter available for list

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

ListDataActivity in Manifest stays without Intent Filter. 
When I click button and start ListDataActivity app. crashes with NullPointerException.
Most interesting is that when I delete ListView from onCreate ListDataActivity runs in normal way displaying blank screen. Could you please tell me what is wrong?
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_all_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ListView>
```

method from DataSource

public Cursor getAllEmployees() {

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Rows in mytable: ---");

// make query of all data from the table and receive instance of Cursor

Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_STAFF, null, null, null, null, null,
        null);

return c;
```

}

Have tried the following

```
case R.id.buttonRead:


    ArrayList<String> value = datasource.getAllEmployees();

    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("123", (ArrayList<String>)value);

    startActivity(intent);

    break;

}
```

changed

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllEmployees() {

ArrayList<String> empList = new ArrayList<String>();

    empList.add("Start");

    return empList;

}
```

as well as ListDataActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

ArrayList<String> value = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("123");




ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view_all_data);



// create Adapter

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, value);

// make adapter available for list

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and it worked fine

Have changed my getAllEmployees to see if everything correct with DB

public void getAllEmployees() {

```
open();

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Rows in mytable: ---");

// make query of all data from the table and receive instance of Cursor

Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_STAFF, null, null, null, null, null,
        null);

// put cursor into position of the first row of required data, if no
// rows false will return

if (c.moveToFirst()) {

    // get columns numbers

    int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID);
    int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME);
    int lastnameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME);
    int positionColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_POSITION);
    int departmentColIndex = c
            .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT);
    int inttelColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_INT_TEL);
    int mobileColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_MOB_TEL);
    int homeColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_HOME_TEL);
    int officemailColIndex = c
            .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_OFFICE_E_MAIL);
    int personalmailColIndex = c
            .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_PERSONAL_E_MAIL);

    do {

        // getting values by column numbers and put them into log

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + c.getInt(idColIndex) + "\n"
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME
                        + c.getString(nameColIndex)
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME
                        + c.getString(lastnameColIndex)
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_POSITION
                        + c.getString(positionColIndex)
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT
                        + c.getString(departmentColIndex)
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_INT_TEL
                        + c.getString(inttelColIndex)
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_MOB_TEL
                        + c.getString(mobileColIndex)
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_HOME_TEL
                        + c.getString(homeColIndex)
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_OFFICE_E_MAIL
                        + c.getString(officemailColIndex)
                        + DBHelper.COLUMN_PERSONAL_E_MAIL
                        + c.getString(personalmailColIndex));

        // move to next row, if no next then end loop

    } while (c.moveToNext());

} else

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "0 rows");

c.close();
```

}

verything works fine with Logs when I call datasource.getAllEmployees(); from MainActivity but when I try to call it from ListDataActivity app crashes. 
**Can someone explain me what is going on?**
Have checked DB everything works fine. When put ListView into the MainActivity everything works fine as well. **WHY IT DOES NOT WORK with another Activity?**

Comment: post your log-cat error.i think error in values fetch from DB.

Comment: log cat posted. any ideas?

Comment: did you get the db values from db correctly.

Comment: yes, logcut dispalys it.

Comment: give me some time to check it on another list within Main activity.

Comment: Can you post your `activity_list_data` XML?

Comment: What is the line that is causing the exception??

Comment: can you remove *FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER* this and try it.

Comment: if I will remove flag SimpleCursorAdapter will be deprecated

Comment: have tried on Main same result

Comment: So you forget use `datasource.open()` or `datasource = new YOURCLASS(this)` in your activity

Comment: you mean in ListDataActivitylet me try

Comment: did it, same thing. makes me more wondering.

Answer (score 0):

you forget use `datasource.open()` or `datasource = new YOURCLASS(this)` in your Oncreate() method

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being annoying to stackoverflow community but it seems that long delay in practicing Android has played a trick with me. Simply forgot to declare variable of DataSource class. PEOPLE be ATTENTIVE to what you do, to yourself and to surrounders!